# Unable to create an iOS project in Stride

Tags: visual-studio, stride

I'm trying out stride but building my project fails for iOS. Windows, mac, and android work until it hits iOS and then it fails. I can create an iOS app in visual studio 2022 fine though. My error is:

```
Verbose: Generating MyGame...
Verbose: Process dependencies for MyGame...
Verbose: Restore NuGet packages for MyGame...
Verbose: Loading Assets from Package [Stride.Engine.sdpkg]
Verbose: Loading Assets from Package [Stride.Graphics.sdpkg]
Verbose: Loading Assets from Package [Stride.Particles.sdpkg]
Verbose: Loading Assets from Package [Stride.Rendering.sdpkg]
Verbose: Loading Assets from Package [Stride.SpriteStudio.Offline.sdpkg]
Verbose: Loading Assets from Package [Stride.Video.sdpkg]
Verbose: Generating MyGame.Windows...
Verbose: Generating MyGame.Linux...
Verbose: Generating MyGame.macOS...
Verbose: Generating MyGame.Android...
Verbose: Generating MyGame.iOS...
Verbose: Process dependencies for MyGame.Windows...
Verbose: Restore NuGet packages for MyGame.Windows...
Verbose: Process dependencies for MyGame.Linux...
Verbose: Restore NuGet packages for MyGame.Linux...
Verbose: Process dependencies for MyGame.macOS...
Verbose: Restore NuGet packages for MyGame.macOS...
Verbose: Process dependencies for MyGame.Android...
Verbose: Restore NuGet packages for MyGame.Android...
Verbose: Process dependencies for MyGame.iOS...
Error: Unexpected exception while loading project [C:\Users\hypes\Documents\Stride Projects\MyGame\MyGame.iOS\MyGame.iOS.csproj] (...)
Verbose: Restore NuGet packages for MyGame.iOS...
[C:\Users\hypes\Documents\Stride Projects\MyGame\MyGame.iOS\MyGame.iOS.csproj(123,3)]: Error: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
[C:\Users\hypes\Documents\Stride Projects\MyGame\MyGame.iOS\MyGame.iOS.csproj(123,3)]: Verbose: Loading Assets from Package [MyGame.sdpkg]
[C:\Users\hypes\Documents\Stride Projects\MyGame\MyGame.iOS\MyGame.iOS.csproj(123,3)]: Verbose: Loading Assets from Package [MyGame.Windows.sdpkg]
[C:\Users\hypes\Documents\Stride Projects\MyGame\MyGame.iOS\MyGame.iOS.csproj(123,3)]: Verbose: Loading Assets from Package [MyGame.Linux.sdpkg]
[C:\Users\hypes\Documents\Stride Projects\MyGame\MyGame.iOS\MyGame.iOS.csproj(123,3)]: Verbose: Loading Assets from Package [MyGame.macOS.sdpkg]
[C:\Users\hypes\Documents\Stride Projects\MyGame\MyGame.iOS\MyGame.iOS.csproj(123,3)]: Verbose: Loading Assets from Package [MyGame.Android.sdpkg]
[C:\Users\hypes\Documents\Stride Projects\MyGame\MyGame.iOS\MyGame.iOS.csproj(123,3)]: Error: Error while pre-loading package [Stride.Core.Assets.Package] (...)
[C:\Users\hypes\Documents\Stride Projects\MyGame\MyGame.iOS\MyGame.iOS.csproj(123,3)]: Verbose: Compiling game assemblies...
[C:\Users\hypes\Documents\Stride Projects\MyGame\MyGame.iOS\MyGame.iOS.csproj(123,3)]: Verbose: Game assemblies compiled...
```

Comment: Did you 'Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk'?

Comment: @DMGregory It doesn't, but I don't know what else to do. I have all the appropriate modules installed in visual studio and can create xamarin apps.

Comment: So you [searched for what to do when this file is missing](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets+missing&ia=web), right? What did you try based on that research?

Comment: @DMGregory It only happens when building a stride game engine studio project though. It works in visual studio, all those questions just pertain to visual studio. This is more of a stride question then visual studio